If $p,q \in \Bbb{N}$ are different primes, then $\Bbb{Z}_p$ is a non free $\Bbb{Z}_{pq}$-module

Denote for every $n \in \Bbb{Z} : \Bbb{Z}_n = \Bbb{Z} / n\Bbb{Z}$. If $p, q \in \Bbb{N}$ are different primes, then $\Bbb{Z} _p$ is a non free $\Bbb{Z}_{pq}$-module .

I am trying to solve this Commutative algebra problem I see on a book but I am struggling with it. My first thought was to do it by contraposition: supose that $\Bbb{Z}_p$ is free and conclude that $p=q,$ but I get confuse when I work with the abstract definition of free module.
The definition I know (I clarify this in case that there is another definition) is the following:

Given $R$ a commutative ring with unity, we say that $M$ is a free $R$-module if there exists a non empty set $I$ with an inclusion $i: I \rightarrow R^I$ (where $R^I = \oplus_{i\in I} R$) such that for every set map $\varphi : I \rightarrow M$ there exists a unique linear map $f: R^I \rightarrow M$ such that $f \circ i = \varphi$

Any possible help to understand the concept and the problem would be appreciated.

I cannot reconcile your definition with the usual definition (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_module). For example, take $R=\Bbb{Z}$ and $M=\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$, and let $I=\lbrace 1\rbrace$ with the inclusion $1\mapsto 1$ into $R$. Then it is true that any map $I\to M$ induces a unique linear map $\Bbb{Z}\to \Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$, namely sending $1$ to whatever element of $M$ was picked out by $I$. But $M$ is torsion, so should not be free.

I agree with @SomeCallMeTim. In fact the condition you've written is true for every $M$ and $I$. This usually called "the universal property of the free module $R^I$". The usual definition of "$M$ is a free module" would be "$M$ is isomorphic to $R^I$ for some $I$" or "there is a set $I$ with an inclusion $I \to M$ such that for every set map $I \to N$ there is a unique linear map $M \to N$ making the diagram commute". Is this what you meant?

@SomeCallMeTim I see, I will write down this, thanks!

@IzaakvanDongen I think so, thanks!

The definition you have in the question is certainly incorrect as pointed out by the others. The standard definition is

A $R$-module $M$ is free if there is an indexing set $I $ such that
$$M\cong\bigoplus_{i\in I}R$$

With this definition, if $\Bbb Z_p$ were a free $\Bbb Z_{pq}$ module, you would have
$$\Bbb Z_p\cong\bigoplus_{i\in I}\Bbb Z_{pq}$$
Now, $I$ cannot be infinite since otherwise, the RHS would be an infinite set and LHS is finite. If $|I|=n$, then you have $p=(pq)^n$, which is clearly not possible.
Hope this helps. :)

Your definition of free R-modules is not correct. You can just define that
(1) $M \cong R^I$ is free. If you really want to define via universal property, you should note that in the category of R-modules, the definition is equivalent to (1).
Then your problem is obvious: $|\mathbb{Z}_p| = p$ and $|\mathbb{Z}_{pq}| = pq$. So there does not exist $I$ such that $\mathbb{Z}_{pq}^I = \mathbb{Z}_p$.
